# How to get parent value based on child value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to get all parent values where the child value (remark) contains "blue", but unfortunately my XSLT works only when the value is at the first child attribute, but it doesn't loop over all child attributes. So how can I search between all "Markers" to find all attribute which is contains "blue"?

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Ford</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>10:40:09</Time>
        <avg>19.3464027998</avg>
        <Markers>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks="Blue"/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
        </Markers>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Ford</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>11:21:56</Time>
        <avg>32.7150023474</avg>
        <Markers>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks="blue"/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
        </Markers>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Ford</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>19:01:27</Time>
        <avg>554.0289810087</avg>
        <Markers>
            <Marker remarks="BLUE"/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
        </Markers>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Ford</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>23:15:26</Time>
        <avg>46.1398232343</avg>
        <Markers>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
        </Markers>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Opel</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>14:05:51</Time>
        <avg>41.7428144493</avg>
        <Markers>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
        </Markers>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Opel</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>15:01:02</Time>
        <avg>65.6303001034</avg>
        <Markers>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks="Yellow"/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
        </Markers>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Date>2023-02-19</Date>
        <Cars>Opel</Cars>
        <SellTarget>A4+</SellTarget>
        <Time>02:00:00</Time>
        <avg>1.2954721559</avg>
        <Markers>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks="Green"/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
            <Marker remarks=""/>
        </Markers>
    </item>
</data>
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <Workbook>
            <Styles>
                <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                    <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                    <Borders/>
                    <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="238" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11"
                        ss:Color="#000000"/>
                    <Interior/>
                    <NumberFormat/>
                    <Protection/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s63" ss:Name="mydefault">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                    <Font ss:FontName="Verdana"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s62" ss:Name="Normal_">
                    <Font ss:FontName="Verdana" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s67" ss:Parent="s63">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                    <NumberFormat ss:Format="yyyy\.mm\.dd"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s69" ss:Parent="s63">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                    <Font ss:FontName="Verdana"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s72">
                    <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center"/>
                    <NumberFormat ss:Format="[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM"/>
                </Style>
            </Styles>
            
            <Worksheet ss:Name="Report">
                
                <Table>
                    <Column ss:Width="63.75"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="31.5"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="61.5"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="50.25"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="87.75"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="56.25"/>
                    
                    <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" >
                        <!-- Date -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <!-- Cars -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">Cars</Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <!-- SellTarget -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">SellTarget</Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <!-- Time -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">Time</Data>
                        </Cell>
                        <!-- avg -->
                        <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                            <Data ss:Type="String">avg</Data>
                        </Cell>
                    </Row>
                    
                    <xsl:for-each select="data/item[contains(translate(Markers/Marker/@remarks, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'blue')]">
                        
                        <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
                            <!-- Date -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String"> 
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <!-- Cars -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Cars"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <!-- SellTarget -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="SellTarget"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <!-- Time -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="Time"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                            <!-- avg -->
                            <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                                <Data ss:Type="String">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="avg"/>
                                </Data>
                            </Cell>
                        </Row>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    
                </Table>
            </Worksheet>
        </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output at the moment:

```
Date        Cars        SellTarget  Time        avg
2023-02-19  Ford        A4+     19:01:27    554.0289810087
```

Expected ouput:

```
Date    Cars    SellTarget  Time    avg
2023-02-19  Ford    A4+ 10:40:09    19.3464027998
2023-02-19  Ford    A4+ 11:21:56    32.7150023474
2023-02-19  Ford    A4+ 19:01:27    554.0289810087
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/item[contains(translate(Markers/Marker/@remarks, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'blue')]">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/data/item[Markers/Marker[contains(translate(@remarks, $uppercase, $lowercase), 'blue')]]">
```

What you have now is providing all of `item`'s remarks as the first argument to the `translate()` function (and then to the `contains()` function). This argument needs to be a string, not a node-set. When you provide a node-set, it is converted to a string by returning the string-value of the first node in the supplied node-set.

Comment: thanks for the quick help, the solution is perfect as always.